# Spring Integration - Wiretap doesn't log when deployed into Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: spring-integration, slf4j, spring-boot-actuator, pcf

We are trying to log the messages using wire-tap interceptor, when the Messageflows through the channels. Wire-tap somehow logins perfectly to console when running locally, but when deployed to the PCF environment, couldn't able to see the logs. Below is the parsing.xml configuration.

```
<int:channel id="logChannel"></int:channel>

<int:message-history/>

<int:wire-tap id="globalWireTap" channel="logChannel" pattern="*"/>
<int:logging-channel-adapter channel="logChannel" level="WARN" expression="headers.history" />
```

Logging dependencies used are:

```
<!-- Logging dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.****</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-impl-spring-4</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-*</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I think anything is not logged under the mentioned `WARN` level. I'm not familiar with PCF, but I can tell that by default a category for that `logging-channel-adapter` is `org.springframework.integration.handler`. So, try to configure an appropriate logging options in the PCF for your project. This is indeed not a Spring Integration problem.

Comment: I'm going to try configuring at "INFO" level, and give a try whether it hooks to the logging system. As far as the logging configurations,  have to research further.